# TextBlock how to Wrap with &#13 with .CS code ;

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, textblock

In the XAML, we can use the  to wrap;

```
<TextBlock Height="219" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,330,0,0" Name="textBlock1" 
          Text="TextBlock&#13;TextBlock" TextWrapping="NoWrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="438" />
```

But i use the code like this:

```
 this.textBlock1.Text = "TextBlock&#13;TextBlock";
```

It doesn't wrap.  I want to how to make it work in the .cs file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
this.textBlock1.Text = "TextBlock" + Environment.NewLine + "TextBlock";
```

but `"TextBlock&#13;TextBlock"` is equal to `"TextBlock\rTextBlock"`

Comment: Now i don't want the string separat. Is any way to set the textBlock1.Text like "TextBlock&#13;TextBlock"?

Comment: @Joel Yes `"TextBlock&#13;TextBlock"` is equivalent to `"TextBlock\rTextBlock"`